# How to solve the issue that user has excceded its 24-hour sending limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, email, nodemailer

Everyone.
Please help me, I am developing contact us form using react and node.js
I built everything front and backend.
It is working for 25 emails in a day, but after that, it shows me this error.
my email is company email. it has own domain.com as you see format of email.

```
error: {code: "EENVELOPE",…}
code: "EENVELOPE"
command: "MAIL FROM"
response: "550 User nermine.maxxx@xxxheia-sxxxos.xxx has exceeded its 24-hour sending limit. Messages to 25 recipients out of 25 allowed have been sent. Relay quota will reset in 7.82 hours."
responseCode: 550
sent: false
```

This mail is goddady email that supposed by outlook.com
After this error, I've chatted with goddady support but he don't give correct answer.
When I send mail in the mail box, it is working well. But only in the contact form, it has limit.

This is source code for node.

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");

exports.sendEmail = (req, res) => {
  const { name, email, message } = req.body;

  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtpout.secureserver.net",
    port: 465,
    secure: true,
    auth: {
      user: "nesss.ssssrem@assssia-ssss.ssss",
      pass: "xxxxxx",
    },
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false,
    },
  });

  const messageHtml = `<div>This is a request sent from the website xxxxx</div><br/><div>${message}</div><br/><div>This is ${name} sending a request from xxxxxxx</div>`;

  const mailOptions = {
    from: "xxxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxx-xxxxx.xxx",
    to: "xxxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxx-xxxxx.xxx",
    subject: "Sending Email From Nermine",
    html: messageHtml,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, function (error, info) {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
      res.status(500).send({ sent: false, error: error });
    } else {
      console.log("Email sent: " + info.response);
      res.status(200).send({ sent: true, result: info.response });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: seems it's been [asked before here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69852191/nodemailer-smtpout-secureserver-net-limited-emails-per-day) and in MANY other places (just do a google search) and not answered anywhere - I think 25 per day is the limit - I guess with godaddy you get what you pay for

Comment: I asked to goddady support and then they told me there is no any limit.

Comment: 500 emails in a day

Comment: ahh, you've fallen for godaddy's lack of knowledge ... 500 emails per day is ONE limit - but the limit imposed by using the API is 25

Comment: oh, Thank you for your advice, Could you tell me how can i solve it?

Comment: if that API has a limit of 25 emails per day, then you fix it by using a different service (and no, I have no recommendations as that would be highly opinionated)

Comment: without to use other service, there is not way?

Comment: and what do you mean other service? about server or other email?

Comment: I'm not saying there is no way to use godaddy's smtp for more than 25 emails a day ... it's just that the question has been asked MANY times over the years, and not one has been answered. as for other service, I mean some other way to use nodemailer to send emails - I have no opinion except to say, I use my own server to send such emails, and I have no limit, since I use my own server

Comment: Use another service link sendgrid.com (I'm not affiliated with them)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps somebody. I spent two days to find the solution. GoDaddy support doesn't help me. It is my working settings for the Django project:

```
host: "smtp.office365.com",
port: 587,
TLS: true,
SSL: false.
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hello Mykhailo Polishchuk, It is working! Thanks. I have the domain with GoDaddy. I was using the host "smtpout.secureserver.net" and getting a 5-send email limit. We should use "smtp.office365.com" and TLS (587).